# Dynamic Multidimensional String Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am only able to add characters to the elements of the array.
How do I add a string to `a[i][j]`, `i` and `j` being integers?

```
    char ** a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 12);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    }
```

When I try to assign `a[0][0]` a string value, it gives a compile error:

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]

Comment: `char **` is not a multidimensional array, but a "pointer to pointer to `char`". It cannot represent a 2D array (less one with more dimensions), but only a "1D array of pointers to `char`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `a[0][0]` has type `char`. You may not assign string literals to objects of type char.

You should use standard C functions `strcpy`, `strncpy`, and `memcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` to copy a string into the dynamically allocated array. Take into account that according to your allocations of the character arrays a string that can be copied in the array has to have only 2 characters including the terminating zero.

For example you can write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( a[0], "A" );
```

Comment: Thanks! Then how would I declare a multidimensional array of strings?

Comment: @BobMarleyandMe You can declare it as you declare any multidimensional array. For example char s[12][12];

Comment: but it needs to be dynamic

Comment: @BobMarleyandMe What is the problem? You allocated dynamic arrays in your post. if the length of string is known at the compile-time you can also write for example char ( *s )[12] = malloc( 12 * sizeof( char[12] ) );

Comment: @BobMarleyandMe There is no string type in C, only char arrays. If you want to store fixed size strings, you could do with a char array of size number-of-strings multiplied by string-size and some pointer arithmetic. If you want to store strings of differing size, you should probably make an array of char* but your strings wouldn't be stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Example will clarify your doubts.

```
int i, len;
char a[][6] = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
char **array ;
array = (char**) malloc (sizeof(int)*4);
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    len = strlen (a[i]);
    len+=1; //for '\0' at end
    printf("\n len for i = %d = %d",i,len);
    *(array+i) = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*len);
    strcpy(array[i], a[i]);
}
 for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    printf("\n&array[%d] = %u &array[%d][0] = %u value = %s",i, &array[i], i, &array[i][0],array[i]);
}
//free memory
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a way that you can declare 2 dimensional array in c

```
   int main()
    {
        char*** pointer=(char***)malloc(sizeof (char*[2][2]) );
        char* str="Hello my str";
        pointer[0][0]=str;
        cout << pointer[0][0]<< endl;
            free(pointer);

        return 0;
    }
```

Just i need you to know tow notes :
1-this array of strings don't contain a llocations to actually store the data or the content of string ,they are just pointers to the data.
2-you cannot do something like this (char***)malloc(sizeof (char*[2][i]) );
as the second dimension must be known in advance to the compiler because it uses it to generate the equation that calculates the amount of memory needed.
but there are other ways that you can declare it completely dynamic without i.